# Is there a fast way to merge overlapping columns between two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

I have a DataFrame with employee information that is missing some records, and want to fill these in using another DataFrame. The way I'm doing it now is below, but takes way too long because it's a lot of rows.

```
df_missing = df_cleaned.loc[(df_cleaned["HOURLY_BASE_RATE"]<= 0) | (df_cleaned["HOURLY_BASE_RATE"].isna())]
df_missing_in_integration = df_missing[["ASSOCIATE_ID", "COUNTRY"]].merge(df_integration_wages, on=["ASSOCIATE_ID", "COUNTRY"])

for index, row in df_missing_in_integration.iterrows():
  associate_id = row["ASSOCIATE_ID"]
  associate_country = row["COUNTRY"]
  associate_index = df_cleaned.index[(df_cleaned["ASSOCIATE_ID"] == associate_id) & (df_cleaned["COUNTRY"] == associate_country)]
  df_cleaned.loc[associate_index, "HOURLY_BASE_RATE"] = row["HOURLY_BASE_RATE"]
  df_cleaned.loc[associate_index, "CURRENCY"] = row["CURRENCY"]
  df_cleaned.loc[associate_index, "PAY_COMPONENT"] = row["PAY_COMPONENT"]
  df_cleaned.loc[associate_index, "FTE"] = row["FTE"]
```

Is there a faster way to fill in those missing values based on a unique combination of the ASSOCIATE_ID and COUNTRY columns? I've tried [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), but this gives me extra columns instead of filling in the values in the existing columns. I've also tried [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), but for some reason I still have the nan values when I try this.

Here's some example DataFrames:

```
df_cleaned = pd.DataFrame({"ASSOCIATE_ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], "COUNTRY": ["USA", "USA", "BEL", "GER", "BEL", "USA", "GER", "GER", "NLD", "NLD"], "HOURLY_BASE_RATE": [15, np.nan, 20, 18, np.nan, np.nan, 43, 38, np.nan, 13], "CURRENCY": ["USD", "USD", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "USD", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"], "PAY_COMPONENT": ["Hourly", np.nan, "Hourly", "Hourly", np.nan, np.nan, "Hourly", "Hourly", np.nan, "Hourly"], "FTE": [1, 1, 0.8, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 0.75, 0.75, np.nan, 1], "LOCATION_TYPE": ["Stores", "Stores", "Distribution Center", "Stores", "Headquarters", "Headquarters", "Headquarters", "Distribution Center", "Stores", "Stores"})
df_integration_wages = pd.DataFrame({"ASSOCIATE_ID": [2, 5, 6, 9, 11, 12], "COUNTRY": ["USA", "USA", "USA", "NLD", "BEL", "BEL"], "HOURLY_BASE_RATE": [2500, 23, 37, 20, 32, 16], "CURRENCY": ["USD", "USD", "USD", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"], "PAY_COMPONENT": ["Monthly", "Hourly", "Hourly", "Hourly", "Hourly", "Hourly"], "FTE": [1, 0.6, 1, 1, 0.8, 1]})
```

I only want to replace the rows where the wage was missing. There are more rows in the integration file, but I don't want to include those. Is there a faster way to achieve what want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert all your negative wages to na

   df_cleaned[df_cleaned["HOURLY_BASE_RATE"] < 0] = np.nan
2. Merge with df_integration_wages

   df_cleaned = df_cleaned.merge(how = 'left', df_integration_wages, on=["ASSOCIATE_ID", "COUNTRY"], suffixes=['old', 'new'])
3. Update missing values:

df_cleaned.loc[df_cleaned['HOURLY_BASE_RATE_old'].isna(),['HOURLY_BASE_RATE_old', 'CURRENCY_old', 'PAY_COMPONENT_old', 'FTE_old'] = df_cleaned[['HOURLY_BASE_RATE_new', 'CURRENCY_new', 'PAY_COMPONENT_new', 'FTE_new']]

4. drop 'new' columns and rename 'old' columns

Comment: So simple! Yet I hadn't thought of it, thank you!

Comment: @mozway I suppose I could have been a little more clear in my question, but there are also other columns in df_cleaned. I didn't include them because I just wanted to target the problem, but with your solution I lose the other values in those columns.

Comment: @MKJ can you provide a reproducible example? I'm happy to update

Comment: @mozway I've added a column!

Comment: @MKJ I'm sorry but I don't see a difference, my current code keeps the "LOCATION_TYPE"  and give the exact same output as your loop

Comment: And also this solution does seem to give the expected output (it's an inner merge and loses most of the rows). You can chose whatever you want but I have to say I don't understand the rationale ;)

Comment: @mozway I've tried again and I don't lose the other values but it also doesn't fill the rows. I can't figure out why, when I tried combine_first earlier it also wasn't working. And yea I realized that so I'm just doing his operations on the rows with the missing data and then replacing those back into the dataframe. Thanks anyway :/

Comment: @MKJ maybe you need to use `df_cleaned.replace(0, np.nan).combine_first(...)`? I assumed you already removed the 0s? Glad you have a working solution in any case

Comment: I've updated it to left merge

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
keys = ['ASSOCIATE_ID', 'COUNTRY']

out = df_cleaned.combine_first(df_integration_wages.merge(df_cleaned[keys],
                                                          how='right'))
```

Output:

```
   ASSOCIATE_ID COUNTRY  HOURLY_BASE_RATE CURRENCY PAY_COMPONENT   FTE
0             1     USA              15.0      USD        Hourly  1.00
1             2     USA            2500.0      USD       Monthly  1.00
2             3     BEL              20.0      EUR        Hourly  0.80
3             4     GER              18.0      EUR        Hourly  1.00
4             5     BEL               NaN      EUR           NaN   NaN
5             6     USA              37.0      USD        Hourly  1.00
6             7     GER              43.0      EUR        Hourly  0.75
7             8     GER              38.0      EUR        Hourly  0.75
8             9     NLD              20.0      EUR        Hourly  1.00
9            10     NLD              13.0      EUR        Hourly  1.00
```